# spark schema rdd to RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I would like to do word count in spark , I created a rdd using spark sql to extract distinct tweets from data set.
I would like to use split function on top of RDD but its not allowing me to do so.

Error:-
valuse split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRdd

Spark Code that doesn't work to do word count:-

```
val disitnct_tweets=hiveCtx.sql("select distinct(text) from tweets_table where text <> ''")
val distinct_tweets_List=sc.parallelize(List(distinct_tweets))

//tried split on both the rdd disnt worked

distinct_tweets.flatmap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

distinct_tweets_List.flatmap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

But when I output the data from sparksql to a file and load it again and run split it works.

Example Code that works:-

```
val distinct_tweets=hiveCtx.sql("select dsitinct(text) from tweets_table where text <> ''")
val distinct_tweets_op=distinct_tweets.collect()
val rdd=sc.parallelize(distinct_tweets_op)
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/bdp/op")
val textFile=sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/bdp/op/part-00000")
val counts=textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
counts.SaveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/bdp/wordcount")
```

I need a answer instead of writing to file and loading again to do my split function is there a work around to make split function work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , its three step process to convert data frame or spark.sql.row.RDD to plain RDD.

sc.parallelize(List())
map to string

```
val distinct_tweets=hiveCtx.sql(" select distinct(text) from tweets_table where text <> ''")
val distinct_tweets_op=distinct_tweets.collect()
val distinct_tweets_list=sc.parallelize(List(distinct_tweets_op))
val distinct_tweets_string=distinct_tweets.map(x=>x.toString)

val test_kali=distinct_tweets_string.flatMap(line =>line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortBy {case (key,value) => -value}.map { case (key,value) => Array(key,value).mkString(",") }
test_kali.collect().foreach(println)

case class kali_test(text: String)
val test_kali_op=test_kali.map(_.split(" ")).map(p => kali_test(p(0)))
test_kali_op.registerTempTable("kali_test")
hiveCtx.sql(" select * from kali_test limit 10 ").collect().foreach(println)
```

This way I don't need to load in a file , I can do my operations on fly.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Although that might work for small pieces of data, it's not a real answer. The RDD retrieved by the `hiveCtx.sql` operation is `collect` to the driver, loosing it's distributed and parallel nature.

Answer (score 1):

First, we should not do collect() and then parallelize to create RDD; that will make driver busy/down.

Rather,

```
val distinct_tweets=hiveCtx.sql("select dsitinct(text) from tweets_table where text <> ''")
val distinct_tweets_op=distinct_tweets.map(x => x.mkstring)
```

[considering that, you select only single column in the query - `distinct(text)`]

now distinct_tweets_op is simply a RDD.

So, loop over this RDD; and you are good to apply split("") function on each string in that RDD.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your first one failed was this line:

```
val distinct_tweets_List=sc.parallelize(List(distinct_tweets))
```

That's a completely useless line in Spark, and worse than useless -- as you saw it tanks your system.

You want to avoid doing `collect()`, which creates an `Array` and returns it to the Driver application. Instead, you want to leave the objects as RDDs as long as possible, and return as little as possible data to the Driver (like the keys and the counts after being reduced).

But to answer your basic question, the following will take a DataFrame consisting of a single StringType column and convert it to an RDD[String]:

```
val myRdd = myDf.rdd.map(_.getString(0))
```

And though SchemaRDDs aren't around anymore, I believe the following will convert SchemaRDD with a single String column to a plain RDD[String]:

```
val myRdd = mySchemaRdd.map(_.getString(0))
```